# Static member 'isSupported' cannot be used on instance of type 'ARConfiguration'

Tags: swift, arkit

getting ' Static member 'isSupported' cannot be used on instance of type 'ARConfiguration' '

```
import ARKit
    // Display Agumented button only if device supports it
    let session = ARSession()
    var sessionConfig: ARConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    if sessionConfig.isSupported {
        bottomBarView.leadingBarButtonItems = [ hButton, fButton, agumentedButton ] }
    else { bottomBarView.leadingBarButtonItems = [ hButton, fButton ] }

    bottomBarView.trailingBarButtonItems = [ aButton, bhButton, cButton ]
  }
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The error message tells you very clearly what the problem is. Read it. Do you not know what "static" and "instance" mean? If not, that would be the place to start. These are very basic Swift concepts.

Comment: This may be a bad question, but it is not "unclear" or "hard to tell what OP is asking" – apparently it could be answered.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly tells you, you must say

```
if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
```

Comment: Except `ARConfiguration` is an abstract base class — reading this property on the base class always returns false. Instead, as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported) suggest, read it on the concrete class you intend to use. OP is using world tracking, so check `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported`.